# Poker hand analysis

Tags: betting-strategy, poker-strategy

NLH tournament in the money
blinds 15 30

sb 1,950 J♠8♠
bb 1,889 K♠Q♣

Prelop
sb bet 75
bb call 75
pot 150

Flop
6♣2♠7♠
sb 45
bb 175
sb call
pot 500

Turn
7♣
sb check
bb check

River
J♣
sb 180
bb 1000
bb ?

Answer (score 1):

Pre flop
sb has a good enough hand to raise
bb has a good enough hand to call

Flop

sb has two overs, flush draw, and a back door straight draw - I get bet for value and maybe even get a fold

bb not sure what that bet is supposed to do.  It is not enough to fold out a draw and trips would check here.  Not sure what he is repping.

when sb calls it is hard to put him on a hand.  Could have a strong draw, 2 pr, or a set.

Turn

sb check is good as bb has taken the lead

bb not sure I like the check but sb did just call your raise

River

sb for sure I don't like this bet.  The hand improved to top pair.  It now has show down value.  Should check and hope to catch a bluff for not too much money.  Call up to a pot size bet.

bb this is a bit of a risky bluff.  A set would have called the flop and bet the turn.  Back door flush draw is a reach but KcQc, or any Ac suited could play this way.  You are repping like 67s?  You are going to get call by trip 7 and sb could be on that hand.

spoiler

> sb folded

Comment: I see the bb raise on the flop not as repping anything, but instead just trying to take control of the hand and get a free card if K or Q doesn't come on the turn. If trying to rep an overpair then he probably would have raised preflop. Could maybe be repping A7 or he's just testing to see if sb completely missed. Side note: that's not a spolier; that's obvious. :D

Comment: Is there a more mathematical explanations here based on equity, etc? It is hard to follow statements which seems to be arbitrary opinions.